# Why shouldnt I use IFormFile for large uploads

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using .net core 2.1

As per Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2) , IFormFile should be used to deal with small uploaded files, whereas MultipartReader should be used for larger files. Fair enough.

However, they also say

> Files uploaded using the IFormFile technique are buffered in memory or on disk on the web server before being processed. Inside the action method, the IFormFile contents are accessible as a stream.

So if large files are sent to disk, and read with a stream, why shouldnt we always use IFormFile? I don’t get the reason why MultipartReader if larger files are not completly loaded in RAM anyway.

Could anyone explain what I’m missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `IFormFile` setup uses a buffering approach, consuming either disk space or memory.

Both disk and memory are resources that can come under pressure if the size or frequency of file uploads is to high, causing **out of disk space** or **out of memory problems**, which can make your site crash.

See the note on that same [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

> Any single buffered file exceeding 64KB will be moved from RAM to a temp file on disk on the server. The resources (disk, RAM) used by file uploads depend on the number and size of concurrent file uploads. Streaming isn't so much about perf, it's about scale. If you try to buffer too many uploads, your site will crash when it runs out of memory or disk space.

A streaming approach via `MultipartReader` doesn't load the full file into memory and doesn't consume any disk space.

Comment: wait, so MultipartReader is not loading completly the file from memory nor disk?

Comment: Still on that same page; it reads per individual `MultipartSection`, which makes it streaming.

Comment: Yes it makes it streaming, but if you save it to disk anyway (as shown in the example) why shouldn't I simply use Iformfile which also saves to disk if the file is large? This isn't what I don't get, can you explain the difference?

Comment: With `IFormFile` a large file gets stored to disk first **on the webserver** before the `ASP.NET MVC action method` gets executed, which in the end might store this image in its actual location (network storage or database, etc.). So it's all about using as little as possible resources of the webserver.

Comment: @pfx How do you get the mime-type when streaming? The mime-type shows 'multipart data' when it should be a file mime type.

Comment: @pfx Thank you, will the temp files used be automatically deleted at some point? what is the strategy used here?

Comment: @YahyaHussein the [issue #7937 on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7973) says "_Yes, the file is marked as DeleteOnClose and closed at the end of the request_".